# Invalid data added/saved (addPerson)

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, validation

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
Boolean valid =  true;
do{
    valid = true;
    //get first name input and valid
    System.out.print("Enter your First Name > ");
    String firstName = sc.nextLine();
    if(firstName.trim().length() > 25){
        valid = false;
    }
    //get last name input and valid
    System.out.print("Enter your Last Name > ");
    String lastName = sc.nextLine();
    if(lastName.trim().length() > 25){
        valid = false;
    }
    //get email input and valid
    System.out.print("Enter your Email > ");
    String email = sc.nextLine();
    if(email.trim().length() > 40){
        valid = false;
    }
      ctrl.addPerson(email, firstName, lastName);

}while(valid == false);
```

User keeps being prompted for invalid input, but invalid data still added/saved (addPerson).
I can understand why invalid is saved, but how should i use the if correctly? thank you for the help!

---

I have read everyone's suggestions and recommendations, below is the editted codes. Hopefully it is better.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean valid =  true;
String firstName = null;
String lastName = null;
String email = null;
Date birthday = null;

        do{
            System.out.print("Enter your First Name > ");
            firstName = sc.nextLine();
        }while(firstName.trim().length() > 25);

        do{     
            System.out.print("Enter your Last Name > ");
            lastName = sc.nextLine();
        }while(lastName.trim().length() > 25);

        do{     
            System.out.print("Enter your Email > ");
            email = sc.nextLine();
        }while(email.trim().length() > 40);

        ctrl.addPerson(email, firstName, lastName);
```

Comment: Try to find out which of the conditions fails. Add some log-output or use a debugger to do this.

Comment: Another refinement would be to declare outside the loop `String firstName, lastName, email = null; //expand to 3 lines..` and within, check for `null` before prompting for that input (again).  It would be frustrating to have to input a long name many times, just because I cannot get my email correct.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes you are right. To make it not so frustrating, I have modified and used three loops to validate right after user input. Sorry I didnt get the "check for null before prompting for that input (again). " part =p

Comment: Your changed code (which is a better idea than my comment) makes it irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put method `addPerson` under condition like

```
if(valid) {
    ctrl.addPerson(email, firstName, lastName);
}
```

I also suggest you to use primitive types (`boolean` instead of `Boolean`), there is no reason to use its object representation here.

Comment: Thank you for the help. In order to inform user warning like this "First name should be <= 25" right after checking, instead of prompt user to key in all details again after done, to achieve this, is if-else a good way?

Comment: @mandy: you should refactor your code. I think what you want is: ask the first name repeatedly until it's valid, then ask the last name repeatedly until it's valid, then ask the email repeatedly until it's valid. So you need 3 loops, and not just one. Try to make short methods. Each loop should be in a single method returning the first name (first method), last name (second method), and email (third method).

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you! I have modified the codes accordingly, it it better now?